# Cannot load installed packages in R - "libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: r, package

I'm using R on a linux server (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS). Occasionally I run into this issue where when trying to load a packages using `library(PACKAGE)` I get the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/USER/R/sf/libs/sf.so':
  libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

in this case when trying to load the `sf` package. However, when I check the directory, the file `/home/USER/R/sf/libs/sf.so` does exist. When this happens it is with code that previously ran and it usually happens with multiple packages (though not all of them).

Checking `.libPaths()` gives

`[1] "/home/USER/R"  "/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/library"`

All my packages are installed in my directory (the first one above) as this is a shared server. Generally, reinstalling these packages (and sometimes dependencies) fixes this problem but that can be time consuming. Is there any other way to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Where did your R package (below `/opt`) come from?  I have been maintaining the _official_ R binary for Debian (and hence Ubuntu) for 20-some years and it is built correctly with a shared library.  You can also get so-called "backports" of the current R for 18.04 if you want to run that old system, see [here](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu) for more.

Comment: I'm not sure unfortunately as I didn't install it but I will check. I'm also not sure of the exact reasoning for having each user install packages in their personal directory so it could be that the shared library works fine but there's some other reason. Thanks!

Comment: No the misfeature you are hitting is due to how that R version was built.

Comment: Ah okay I see, in that case I will try to get the official version installed.

Comment: In case you have colleagues who have policies that require local builds, ensure that `--enable-R-shlib` is set at configuration time.  The pre-made binaries are a safe bet.